# What is the cost of adding a new column in BigQuery table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I tried to search for this and found that from "Free operation" section of https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

> You are not charged for list, get, patch, update and delete calls.
>   Examples include (but are not limited to): listing datasets, updating
>   a dataset's access control list, and updating a table's description.

But I am not sure if this also means table schema update.

As I can assume because BigQuery is a columner data storage , Adding a new column should not incur any cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new column does not incur query or storage costs. The new column will have `NULL` values for all existing rows in the table.

Comment: Thanks Elliott Brossard